# Why does windows remove spaces from filenames

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Since repairing Windows 11 recently (my files were kept), in many folders, files that I had named xxx – xxx now omit the space before the hyphen.
Filenames have changed from, for example, 123 - 456 to 123- 456
Is there a setting somewhere that makes windows do this?

Comment: To clarify, filenames have changed from, for example, 123 - 456 to 123- 456

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of clarifying your question with a temporary comment.

Answer (score -1):

File/folder names cannot begin with a space in Windows.
Specifically, "The Win32 API strips trailing period (full-stop), and leading and trailing space characters from filenames, except when UNC paths are used."
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename .

Comment: This is not true. I just tested a simple CreateFile with leading spaces and it worked. The documentation for naming files only mentions trailing spaces/dots. Windows Explorer does trim leading spaces, though. Might be a quirk of the repair tool. Also, the OP's question is kinda poorly worded since there is no leading space visible in that example text.

Comment: @theultramage: It might be possible that one could find ways to somehow create files with trailiing spaces, but windows by default does not support it. Most people don't code to create filenames.

Comment: example in question is not about leading or trailing spaces "xxx - xxx".

Comment: "File/folder names cannot begin with a space in Windows." - The author's example does not begin with space. You might want to read the question and clarify your answer.